# Convert URLRequest to NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to convert a `URLRequest` to a `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3.0 but I can't get it to work. This is the code I have:

```
var request = self.request
URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "", in: request)
```

But it says

> cannot convert type URLRequest to type NSMutableURLRequest.

When I try to cast using 'as' it just says the cast will always fail. What do I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basics of this are get a mutable copy, update the mutable copy then update request with the mutable copy.

```
let mutableRequest = ((self.request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest)!
URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "", in: mutableRequest)
self.request = mutableRequest as URLRequest
```

It would be better to use avoid the forced unwrap.

```
guard let mutableRequest = (self.request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest else {
    // Handle the error
    return
}

URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "", in: mutableRequest)
self.request = mutableRequest as URLRequest
```

Note: `self.request` must be declared `var` not `let`.

Comment: Perfect it seems casting it to NSURLRequest then getting the mutable copy doesn't throw an error but I thought I had tried this and it didn't work. I guess I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Creating a new (mutable) request and replacing the original request won't work when trying to set the property on a request you don't own. For example, in `webView(_:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:)`. Any suggestions for that scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 10 SDK `MutableURLRequest` is deprecated in favor of using `URLRequest` struct type with `var` keyword. Also `URLRequest` [is bridged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest) to `NSMutableURLRequest` so you can safely make forced casts:

```
let  r = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!) as! NSMutableURLRequest
URLProtocol.setProperty("Hello, world!", forKey: "test", in: r)
print(URLProtocol.property(forKey: "test", in: r as! URLRequest)!)
```

Comment: This works fine, but when I call
```swift
URLProtocol.property(forKey: "test", in: request)
```
from another method when the request is sent back to me, it always comes back `nil`

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift 4.1, the following solution worked for me

```
if let mutableRequest = (request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest {
    mutableRequest.addValue("VALUE", forHTTPHeaderField: "KEY")
    print(mutableRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

work in swift 5

```
guard let mutableRequest = (self.request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest else {
            // Handle the error
            return
        }
URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "protocolKey", in: mutableRequest)
```